# C# Program with if else statements returning some absurd value

Tags: c#, if-statement, console

```
`class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int Likes = 1;

        Likes = Console.Read();

        if (Likes == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Friend1 likes your post");
        }
        else if (Likes == 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Friend1 and Friend2 like your post");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Friend1 and Friend2 and" + Likes + "number of  
  other people like your post");
        }
        `
```

Output: 
1
Friend1 and Friend2 and49number of other people like your post
Press any key to continue. . .

Comment: How about reading the documentation of `Console.Read()`? *Hint*: it obviously doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Ya, Understood. Thanks. I have to use .parse() right?

Comment: yes that's right...

Comment: Btw, u've got a little error. Don't forget to insert into last `else` this: `Likes -= 2;` to display correct result.